# how can I get the agent/_work/[##] folder number in build script?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying to access the folder number when running a build. How can I get this value as a $(someparameter.name) for use in the script?

I've scrubbed through the Pipelines predefined variables, and that working folder number is included in some of the values, but not JUST the number.

For example: ...Build\$(Agent.Name)\_work\**47**\s\...  <<<< what contains the "47" value?

Please advise.
A

Answer (score 0):

I am afraid that there is no out-of-box predefined variable can get the agent folder name.

To get the agent folder name, you can use the Pipeline variable: **$(Pipeline.Workspace)** to get the workspace path(e.g. `/home/vsts/work/1`). Then you can use the PowerShell script to get the folder number of the workspace path and set the number as Pipeline variable for next tasks.

For example:

```
steps:
- powershell: |
   echo $(Pipeline.Workspace)
   
   
   
   $foldernumber = "$(Pipeline.Workspace)".Split("\")[-1]
   
   echo $foldernumber
   
    echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=foldernumber]$foldernumber" 
  displayName: 'PowerShell Script'

- powershell: |
   echo $(foldernumber)
```

Comment: I suspected as much. I'll try this approach. Thanks!

Comment: I tried the approach above, but I REALLY need to set this value to a variable that is declared outside of the powershell script at the top of the Pipeline Build Script "$(folderNumber)". I'm trying the following with no luck........
   echo $(Pipeline.Workspace) 
   $folderNumber = "$(Pipeline.Workspace)".Split("\")[-1] 
   echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=folderNumber]$folderNumber" 
   Write-Host "PWS Folder Number | $folderNumber" <<<correct 
   Write-Host "VAR Folder Number | $(folderNumber)" <<<nothing 
   Write-Host "VAR Folder Number | $env:folderNumber" <<<nothing

Answer (score 0):

After much trial and error, this works to update a declared DevOps Build Pipeline variable using a PowerShell step in the build. It's pretty simple.

```
variables:
  workDirectory: ''
  
steps:
- powershell: |  
   $env:workDirectory = "NewValueHere"
   echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=workDirectory]$($env:workDirectory)" 

- later steps in script
$(workDirectory) has correct updated value
```